# Modificar Tupla desde Haskell

Tags: haskell

¿Cómo puedo modificar una tupla en un archivo `txt` desde *Haskell*?

Tengo un archivo **.hs** donde tiene el ejemplo que está abajo, yo lo que quiero saber es cómo agregar otra tupla al archivo desde `WinGhci`.

Ejemplo:

```
alumnos :: [(Integer,[Char],Integer,Double,Double,Double,Double )]

alumnos = [
    (16320100, "Alex", 20, 24.23, 45.21, 26.16, 60.90),
    (16320101, "Emy", 21, 59.23, 12.55, 61.97, 85.04)
]
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, ya corregí mi duda.

Comment: No sé si entiendo bien. ¿Quieres añadir más elementos a la lista una vez interpretado el código o lo que quieres es cambiar el texto del código en el fichero? Lo primero es simplemente `++` o `concat`

Answer (score 2):

Es una solución bastante artesanal (por no decir horrible), pero debería funcionarte en tanto que no cambies el formato de alumnos en el archivo.

Aclaración: alumnos es una lista, no una tupla. Por ende la pregunta está mal formulada porque no querés modificar ninguna tupla, sino la lista.

Ahora sí, manos a la obra:

```
import Data.List

main =
  do text <- readFile "Nombre del archivo" -- Leemos todo el texto que hay en el archivo. Acá hay que reemplazar Nombre del archivo por tu archivo, incluyendo la extensión .hs.
     let text' = take (length text - 1) text -- Estamos dejando de lado el corchete que cierra a la lista.
     let text'' = text' ++ "Tu tupla" -- Agregamos los datos nuevos.
     writeFile "Nombre del archivo" text''
```

Lo único que me genera dudas es si writeFile agrega texto al final del archivo o escribe desde el principio pisando lo que estuviera antes, pero debiera funcionar. Cualquier cosa no me molesta que lo hagas notar. Saludos!